# How to get datasource query From PowerBI Datasets

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

We have hundreds of datasets where one or more table has source to AnalysisService Tabular (Import mode). On Analysis Service we have set up a log (extended events), where we can find how long the query was processed.

Now I wonder how to find from which Powerbi Report/Dataset certain queries come from. That I can point the business users to change some of the bad performing queries to better ones. I can't find a way to find this.

Is there a way to do that? Can we list a dataset with queries?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, or at least not exactly. One option is, if you have Power BI Premium, to use [Metrics app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-metrics-app) to find the reports with highest query wait times. Another option is to you the [Scanner API](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-scanner-api-admin-rest-apis-enhancements-to-include-dataset-tables-columns-measures-dax-expressions-and-mashup-queries/), which can give you the tables used in each model.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard about the Scanner API, I'll check what it offers.